# How to pass parameter to jQuery dialog("close")?

Tags: jquery, dialog

Research so far: I found one answer that suggests using a global variable declaration in order to make a global variable available to the dialog code, but I think that's a shotgun approach. I wish to specifically pass a variable to the close: of my .dialog box.

Problem: Unable to pass a parameter to the close: section of my dialog box.

Most recently I have tried this code, which follows a form submit():

```
document.forms['dsEntryForm'].submit();
myTalk.data('timestamp', timestamp); //assign the ID for later
myTalk.dialog("close");
```

...where **myTalk** is the variable assigned to my dialog box, **timestamp** is a UTC value, and in the close I want it to perform a series of operations:

```
    close: function(data){
          clearForm(document.forms['dsEntryForm']);
          CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData('');
          if(document.getElementById('formsubmitted')){
            document.getElementById('formsubmitted').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('formsubmitted'));
          }
          getNewMessage(data.timestamp);
    }
```

However, when I debug the value of **data.timestamp** by using an `alert(data.timestamp);` the result is **undefined**.

Comment: In the posted code, data.timestamp won't exist because the argument to the close method is named data. So, unless whatever is being passed as an argument to close happens to have a timestamp property, it will always be undefined.

Comment: I added a timestamp property to the data object before invoking dialog("close"). I used the parameter passing method I have successfully used when invoking an .ajax.

Comment: I see that you added the timestamp property to myTalk.data, but myTalk.data != data in the context of the close method. In the jquery-ui, the first argument to the close method is the event, which is being assigned to data according to the posted code. That is why the $(this).data solution below works.

Comment: Explanation noted, thanks bstakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog `close` event receives arguments `event` and `ui`, no data like you are trying to use.

If you have set your data using the `data-timestamp` attribute then you can access it in the close event like this:

```
close: function(){
    console.log( $(this).data('timestamp') );
}
```

- [Close event docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)

Comment: ended up using the following which you helped me find
    onClose: function(){FunctionIWantToCall(parameter1, param2);}